# Leaves not liked by herbivores

Tags: zoology, botany, food, nutrition

I at times have many goats grazing in our locality. Recently a few cows were seen too. I just offered one of the cows a few leaves from *Jasminum sambac* plant growing in our garden. The cow smelled and left those leaves untouched. However on being given mango leaves, not a bit of it remained. The same situation did I observe with goats.I have the following questions:

What is the difference between leaves of others and leaves of *Jasminum sambac*?
Why do herbivores avoid consumption of these leaves?
Does it happen with other leaves too?

Comment: No idea why the cow hate it. Its a rabbit safe plant: http://wabbitwiki.com/wiki/Vegetables

Comment: I havent ever experimented with rabbits. However this is a practical situation in case of cows and goats. I have observed this a number of times, since I was small

Comment: Some animals don't like any unusual smelling or textured foliage. I've noticed that deer will avoid many non-toxic plants that rabbits enjoy. I've noted that deer avoid aromatic, slimy, prickly, hairy, spicy, etc, and prefer plants like hostas, which taste similar to lettuce.

Comment: what about regular herbivores...cows and goats??

Comment: Goats will eat almost anything, including the canvass on your convertible mustang :(.

Comment: Goats will eat bark off a full grown oak tree.

Comment: We havent got oaks growing here...yes, I have seen goats eating leaves of different types...but I wanted to know, why they do not like the above mentioned!!!

Comment: I have noticed goats eating film posters and banners stuck on walls but yes I do remember them avoiding certain leaves. Could be just like some of us hate some food items while other might hate it.. They have their preferences. Might be that the leaf you offered   could have been eaten by another cow.

Comment: I have seen cattle eat the flowers off thistles if they get hungry enough, they wrap their tongue around the back of the flower and pull it off. The rest of the plant is too thorny. But about herbivores avoiding some plants, many plants have defensive mechanisms such as raphides, tiny needles of calcium oxalate which are extremely irritating to the tissues in the mouth and esophagus and can create holes in cells that allow toxic plant proteins inside. Maybe some of these plants have raphides.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cattles actually hate shrubs which are very tough to break and tasteless(for a cow). Some plants they won't touch are:

- *Lantana urticoides* (West Indian shrub verbena),
- *Malvaviscus arboreus* var.*drummondii* (wax mallow)
- *Rhus copallinum* (winged sumac)
- *Viburnum acerifolium* (mapleleaf viburnum).
- *Morella cerifera* (wax myrtle)
- *Ilex vomitoria* (yaupon).

Source:

https://www.wildflower.org/expert/show.php?id=2108

---

[image]

*Lantana urticoides*

http://www.wellgrowhorti.com/Pictures/Landscape%20Plants/Shrubs/Web%20Pictures1/M/Malvaviscus%20Arboreus.jpg

*Malvaviscus Arboreus*

http://www.floridata.com/wallpaper/jpg/Rhus_copallinum_frt800.jpg

*Rhus copallinum*

[image]
<sub>(source: [naturallandscapesnursery.com](http://www.naturallandscapesnursery.com/VibcassinoidesMound.JPG))</sub>

*Viburnum acerifolium*

[image]

*Morella cerifera*

[image]

*Ilex vomitoria*

Comment: Also see [**'Is there a grassy plant that's unattractive to livestock without being poisonous?'**](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/7507/is-there-a-grassy-plant-thats-unattractive-to-livestock-without-being-poisonous) and [**'What kind of landscaping plants do livestock avoid eating and need minimal attention?'**](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/3099/what-kind-of-landscaping-plants-do-livestock-avoid-eating-and-need-minimal-atten)